# Eclipse PRE_DELETE resource change event

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Eclipse plugins can be notified of changes to resources by using a resource change listener.

When a project is being deleted, the resource change listener is notified and a IResourceChangeEvent is passed to it. Using the code below, it is possible to get the type of the event.

```
    @Override
public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
    switch (event.getType()) {
    case IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_DELETE:
        // do something
        break;
    }
}
```

But when a project is being deleted in eclipse, the user can choose to delete the project from the file system or from the workspace only.

Is there a way to distinguish between this two cases in the resource change listener ?

Edit: 
What I am trying to do is the following: I have two projects A and B where B depends on A. When A is deleted, I want B to be deleted as well. If A is deleted from the file system, I want B to be also deleted from the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible for a reason: Eclipse plugins are expected to only use and know the workspace resources. From an architecture point of view, there is nothing outside of the workspace. If an Eclipse plugin is doing something with files (besides of export/import tasks), then that's typically wrong.

So for your plugin it must not matter whether the underlying files are deleted, if IResources are deleted.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question and added more information about what I'm trying to achieve.